# How can I make the legend horizontal in the euler plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram, eulerr

I'm having difficulty styling this euler plot. One of my main issues is that I'd like the legend to be on the bottom, but display the variables horizontally. They look strange stacked vertically.

If anyone also knows how to adjust the margins, add a border around the whole plot, and add a subtitle, I'm stumped on those things too. I've already tried par(mar) and that didn't have any effect.

```
fit1 <- euler(c("Day 1" = 69, "Day 2" = 109, "Day 3" = 152,
                "Day 1&Day 2" = 11, "Day 1&Day 3" = 18, "Day 2&Day 3" = 28,
                "Day 1&Day 2&Day 3" = 2))

col <- c("#66D2D6", "#FBC740", "#E56997")

plot(fit1,
     quantities = TRUE,
     fills = list(fill = col, alpha = 0.8),
     edges = "black",
     main = list(label = "test", cex = 0.9),
     legend = list(side = "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't used `lattice` much, but try adding `columns = 3` to your legend list ... taking the idea from [this blog post](https://www.magesblog.com/post/2012-12-04-changing-colours-and-legends-in-lattice/)

Comment: @GregorThomas:  `euler` is in the `eulerr` package, not in `lattice`.

Answer (score 2):

The `plot` method for `euler` objects uses `grid::grid.legend()` to plot the legend.  You can specify any of `grid.legend`'s arguments in the `legend` argument to `plot` (which really calls `plot.euler`).  To get a horizontal legend, use

```
plot(fit1,
     quantities = TRUE,
     fills = list(fill = col, alpha = 0.8),
     edges = "black",
     main = list(label = "test", cex = 0.9),
     legend = list(side = "bottom", nrow = 1, ncol = 3))
```

Comment: Thanks!! I had tried ncol = 3 and nrow = 1 separately but didn't realize they needed to be used together. This worked perfectly.

Comment: That's not necessary for `grid::grid.legend`, but `plot.euler` kind of messes things up in its `legend` argument.